# Solid FFMPEG in background worker fails on user pc

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, backgroundworker

I'm using Solid FFPEG to rip out individual frames from a video, I'm using this to 'play' the video (so it rips out each frame). I'm using a background worker to keep the UI responsive. Running on my PC I have no problems, but on the test PC it will not display the frames, I get the below error from the background workers RunWorkerCompleted method.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'CAVEditLib.ICAVConverter'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{59C19DEF-02ED-44CD-BFD8-2FD09DBDC9F9}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)) at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
   at CAVEditLib.ICAVConverter.get_AVPrope()
   at RoutePlotter.VideoManager.UpdateAllFrames(Decimal frontNumericValue, Decimal backNumericValue, Decimal leftNumericValue, Decimal rightNumericValue)
   at RoutePlotter.MainForm.backgroundWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

The cavEditLib.dll file seems to be registered on the Test PC, but the background worker won't work.

Thanks fro any help.

Comment: I'll just ask the stupid question - did you reboot the PC after installing the software the places cavEditLib.dll on the Test PC's drive / registry?

Comment: and if you run this without background worker it works?

Comment: PC has been rebooted, didn't make any difference unfortunately. And it does work without the background worker, but works with the background worker on my PC, and certain other ones, but not the testers PC.